# lambda macro in elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

Here is the short lambda macro definition taken from subr.el.

```
  (defmacro lambda (&rest cdr)
      (list 'function (cons 'lambda cdr)))
```

The fact, this is a recursive macro puts me in a fix. can someone explain, how this works & what it returns:

```
(list 'function (cons 'lambda cdr))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this is not a recursive macro is that `function` acts like `quote` in that it prevents evaluation of its argument.  Therefore, a recursive call to the `lambda` macro will not be made.

The difference between `function` and `quote` is that `function` permits byte compilation of its argument, while `quote` always preserves it verbatim.  Thus, if you write `(lambda () 1)`, it will be expanded to `(function (lambda () 1))`, and then replaced with byte code by the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a recursive macro. Emacs Lisp macros have the form `(SYMBOL...)`. It is only such a form that gets defined as a macro, and which is expanded.  The occurrence of the symbol `lambda` in the macro definition body is not expanded.  It is a `(` followed by the symbol `lambda` and a possibly empty list of sexps, and then a `)` that is matched and expanded.

The macro expansion returns the list `(function (lambda CDR))`, where `CDR` is the (unevaluated) list of sexps passed as args to the macro. When that *list* is evaluated it returns the list `(lambda CDR)`, with the same (unevaluated) CDR.